# Header is not showing in JTable

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jscrollpane

This is one part of my whole code. I press button show movies then goes to new frame and must show table. its happen but without header/heading part of the table

```
    //Record Show 
    if(e.getSource()==ShowMovies){
        Frame frame = new JFrame("Show Movies");
        frame.setBounds(10, 20, 500, 500);

        Container cntr = frame.getContentPane();
        cntr.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE); 

        //f=new JFrame();    

        String col[] = {"ID","NAME","SALARY"}; 
        String data[][] = { 
                {"101","Amit","670000"},    
                {"102","Jai","780000"},    
                {"101","Sachin","700000"}};    

        JTable jt=new JTable(data,col);    
        jt.setBounds(100,40,300,300); 
        jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400,50));
        jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(jt);
        frame.add(jt);    
    }
```

Comment: Do not set the size of the `JTable`, set the size of the `JScrollPane`....

Comment: 1) Don't use `null layout`! Use proper layout managers! Or `setBounds(...)`. 2) Call `setVisible(true);` on the `JFrame` after you've added all elements to it, not before. 3) You're adding the `JTable` to the `JFrame` directly, instead add the `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame`, Swing components can only be added to a container once (This is maybe the solution to your problem, but follow recommendations 1 and 2 please as both of them are related to your problem (or future problems)), i.e. `frame.add(jsp);` instead of `frame.add(jt);`

Comment: @Frakcool thanks brother. Problem has resolved. i put table in jpannel and add jpannel in frame according to your suggestion. Issue has resolved. thanks again

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `null layout`! Use proper layout managers! And don't use `setBounds(...)`.
2. Call `setVisible(true);` on the `JFrame` after you've added all elements to it, not before.
3. You're adding the `JTable` to the `JFrame` directly, instead add the `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame`, Swing components can only be added to a container once (This is maybe the solution to your problem, but follow recommendations 1 and 2 please as both of them are related to your problem (or future problems)).

   Change:

   ```
   frame.add(jt);
   ```

   To:

   ```
   frame.add(jsp);
   ```

Comment: I believe you have your “Change:“ and “To:” code sections reversed.

Comment: @VGR you're right, I wrote my answer in a hurry and didn't notice that, thanks for pointing at that error :) already corrected ^^

Answer (score 0):

Put your JTable inside a JScrollPane. Try this:

```
add(new JScrollPane(jt));
```